# UML model for CAN communication

Tags: uml

If i want to communicate between 5 controllers using Control area network (CAN) communication, What diagram i have to use?

I want to generate code from the diagram and use it later. Is it possible to modle a diagram which shows CAN communication between controllers and later a C/C++ code is generated?

Comment: See http://www.uml-diagrams.org/communication-diagrams.html

Comment: I think from communication diagrams it is not possible to generate code. But i want to generate code.

Comment: Hehe, you cloned my avatar xD Don't expect a different answer here than on Sparx' forum: http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,37427.0/topicseen.html

Comment: Often it's a good idea to cross-post here. But I guess in your case the answers at Sparx are already the end of the road. Maybe you could explain on Sparx' forum WHY you want to generate code.